# CORS preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, rest, cors

I am trying to make a GET/POST Request to my Wordpress REST API using Authorization Headers but in response i am getting

preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

I am using JWT Authentication for WP-API for Authentication and tried almost every possible option found on the internet but no luck.

Have a look at my current .htaccess configurations

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
  <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    SetEnvIf Origin "^(http://localhost:3000)$" CORS=$0
  </IfModule>
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{CORS}e env=CORS
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true" env=CORS
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD" env=CORS
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*" env=CORS
  Header set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "*" env=CORS
  <FilesMatch "\.(php|html)$">
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

I am getting this error when the request is made from axios

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'HIDDEN_SERVER_ADDRESS' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

In PostMan the calls are working fine and giving desired results.

Comment: _“In PostMan […]”_ - irrelevant, that is not a scenario where CORS applies in the first place. `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]` – that only tries to set the status code at this point, but the request still gets passed through to whatever script handles this URL route - so if that script then issues a different status code, it will simply overwrite this.

Comment: I am setting 200 Status code when OPTION headers are sent so my preflight request is validated. What can be the possible solution for this?

Comment: _“so my preflight request is validated”_ - yeah, unless – what I just said … Just because you set the status code in .htaccess, doesn’t mean your PHP script - which still gets called with this request method - might not override it. (F.e. if it runs into a fatal error, because expected request data is missing.)

Answer (score 29):

Trying every possible solution in .htaccess didn't help in my case. So if anyone else is on the same page here is a solution that worked for me.

put this code in the index.php file and it will work like a charm.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization");
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if ($method == "OPTIONS") {
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization");
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
die();
}
```

Comment: What I don't like in your code is `die()`. If you remove it, it is quite possible that it still wouldn't work.

Comment: Because you kill the process with `die()`. So everything after `die()` won't be executed.

Comment: i was working on a headless wordpress application so in my case die() was necessary

Comment: i tried everything and this is the only solution that worked for me thanks. Having said that its probably a good idea to actually set the allow origin to the URLS that you expect to make request. For private APIs at least.

Comment: I have spent like 8 hours looking for this.

Comment: i am sure they created options request to solve some issues but they created others...

Answer (score 4):

The solution provided by Azaz Khan worked for me. I searched for why it worked and I found [this](https://medium.com/@raminahmadi/what-is-http-method-options-2419616a5daf) about request with OPTIONS method

> when using Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), a preflight request with OPTIONS is being automatically sent, so the target resource would respond with acceptable parameters. In normal web development scnario, there is no need to make an OPTION call as it is being issued by browsers.

So I think before the auth request, a request with OPTIONS method has been fired, but the backend API did not give back a 200 OK response. For me the backend sent back a PHP error, maybe a 404 http error, I did not checked, but with this code I am sure the API gives back 200 OK response because of the exit:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Authorization,X-Requested-With');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
  header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
  exit();
}
```