# Postman API error: "It does not have HTTP ok status." (JS)

Tags: javascript, api, cors

I am tasked with writing a web app where users must enter their email, and then some user reports will return to them. It's written in JavaScript. There is already an API for this in Postman.

I was able to get the data well from Postman. The data can only be obtained from entering the parameter userToken, which in turn must be obtained from a separate API where you login with your username and password. Simply put, there are two API's. One is to log in, and return the userToken, and the second one is retrieving records by posting the userToken.

**What I did previously:**
Wrote a previous function that logs in to the API and retrieve the userToken. I used to have this error (Access-Control-Allow-Origin missing, but it's fixed.

I installed CORS extension in Google, and then installed something that will maintain cors thru NPM (I forgot the name).

**What I am facing:**
The login API works like a charm, but when I tried to get the results, I am greeted with this new error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://[----].com/report/list' from origin 'null'
> has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't
> pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

**What I tried:**
I added the following code:

```
myHeaders.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            myHeaders.append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
            myHeaders.append("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS")
            myHeaders.append("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true)
```

but it doesn't work.

This is my entire code:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="Default.css">
      <div>
         <img src="Images/imageedit_1_2384739357.png" height=200 width=200 class="center"/>
         <hr>
     </div>
   </head>
   <body>   

      <script language = "javascript" type = "text/javascript">
       //The code snippet from Postman:
            var myHeaders = new Headers();
            myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
            myHeaders.append("userToken", "[----------]=");
            myHeaders.append("Cookie", ".AspNetCore.Session=[-----------]");

            var raw = JSON.stringify({
              "time": 0
            });

            var requestOptions = {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: myHeaders,
              body: raw,
              redirect: 'follow'
            };

            fetch("https://[-----------].com/report/list", requestOptions)
              .then(response => response.text())
              .then(result => console.log(result))
              .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
      </script>
</html>
```

How can I Solve this problem? What did I do wrong?

Edit: It's in Javascript, not PHP!

Comment: First of all, I'm using JS, not PHP. Secondly, how can I add this HTTP 200 header? Sorry, but I have to say that's irrelevent.

Comment: You cannot use the wildcard (`*`) in conjunction with `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`. Try specifying a single allowed origin instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57901808/cors-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check-it-does-not-have-http)

Comment: @EJoshuaS - Reinstate Monica it was proposed before, but it didn't help, and it's in PHP.